# Customising counter within enumerate-list

Tags: lists, numbering, enumerate

Please consider the following code. I would like to use the `enumerate`-environment to generate a list, which (for better understanding) I built with the `tabular`-environment. I would like to have the second item labeled as "2-5.".

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=a4]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ngerman}

\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}
\item bla
\item bla bla
\item bla bla bla
\end{enumerate}


\begin{table}[htbp]
   \begin{tabular}{rl}
1. & bla \\
2-5. & bla bla   \\
6. & bla bla bla  \\
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: What exactly do you want the customized enumeration to be like. Be more specific. You mean the enumerate 2-5 is brought together in one `\item[2-5]` sort of input?

Comment: @azetina: Thx for the comment. Please see edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to resume the numbering after a modification

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=a4]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ngerman}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item bla \stepcounter{enumi}
\item[\theenumi--5.] bla bla \setcounter{enumi}{5}
\item bla bla bla
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Thanks to egreg and Mico for the correction/modification!

[image]

Comment: You should add the period: `\item[\theenumi-5.]`.

Comment: To highlight that you're dealing with a range of numbers rather than a simple "dash", you may want to to write `\item[\theenumi--5.]` (the `--` will be typeset as an en-dash).

Comment: @Mico That's better, thank you. I've updated the code accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for the optional argument to `\item`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=a4]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}


\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}
\item bla
\item[2--5.]\addtocounter{enumi}{4} bla bla
\item bla bla bla
\end{enumerate}


\begin{table}[htbp]
   \begin{tabular}{rl}
1. & bla \\
2-5. & bla bla   \\
6. & bla bla bla  \\
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```